# R Shiny dropdownButton closed immediately on click

Tags: r, shiny, dropdown

I observed this issue only when I created **dropdownButton** on server side:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   uiOutput("uiWidget")
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$uiWidget <- renderUI({
    dropdownButton(
    label = "Controls",
    icon = icon("sliders"),
    status = "primary",
    circle = FALSE,
    sliderInput(
       inputId = "n",
       label = "Number of observations",
       min = 10, max = 100, value = 30
    ),
    prettyToggle(
       inputId = "na",
       label_on = "NAs keeped",
       label_off = "NAs removed",
       icon_on = icon("check"),
       icon_off = icon("remove")
    ))
   })
})
```

For the above code, when I click the inside sliderInput, the popup will be closed immediately. However, it works fine when I created the **dropdownButton** on ui.R.
The following is the source code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  dropdownButton(
  label = "Controls",
  icon = icon("sliders"),
  status = "primary",
  circle = FALSE,
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "n",
    label = "Number of observations",
    min = 10, max = 100, value = 30
  ),
  prettyToggle(
    inputId = "na",
    label_on = "NAs keeped",
    label_off = "NAs removed",
    icon_on = icon("check"),
    icon_off = icon("remove")
  ))
))
```

What's the explanation for this? I also noticed that the **dropdown** in package shinyWidgets has the consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the described behaviour.
The dropdown menu remains open, when changing the slider or toggling the "na"-input.

Maybe update your shiny-package and check again? My shiny-version is 1.0.5 and shinyWidgets 0.4.2

Comment: You are correct. After upgrading shinyWidgets, there is no such issue anymore.